# Fatal error: Call to undefined method Security::sanitize_filename()

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am getting this error of file upload in codeigniter. I am using the MX_Controller for the moduler development. I have tried the **$this->security->sanitize_filename()** but still not working. Please, check below my code for the model, view and controller.

**controller code for do_upload function**

```
 function do_upload()
  {
    // $filename = $this->security->sanitize_filename($this->input->post('upload_file'));
    $config['upload_path']   = './uploads/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
    $config['max_size']      = 10000;
    $config['max_width']     = 10024;
    $config['max_height']    = 7608;
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    $this->upload->initialize($config);
    if(!$this->upload->do_upload('upload_file')) {
        // $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
        // $this->load->view('upload_form', $error);
        echo($this->upload->display_errors());
    } else {
        echo($this->upload->data());
        // $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
        // $this->load->view('upload_success', $data);
   }
}
```

**code for view**

```
<div class="portlet-body form">
     <!-- BEGIN FORM-->
     <?php $attributes = array("class"=>"horizontal-form", "id"=>"file_upload_form"); echo form_open_multipart('Doupload/do_upload', $attributes); ?>
      <div class="form-body">
      <!--/row-->
       <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-6">
           <div class="form-group">
              <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo($user_id);?>" name="user_id" id="user_id">
               <input type="file" class="file" name="upload_file" id="upload_file">
                 <div id="errorBlock" class="help-block"></div>
              </div>
           </div>
         </div>
     </div>
     <div class="form-actions right">
        <button type="button" class="btn default">Cancelar</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn" id="submit">Submit</button>
    </div>
 </form>
 <!-- END FORM-->
```

**model code for fileSave function**

```
 public function fileSave($dataArray)
    {
        $savefile = $this->db->insert('mod_financial_user_invoice', $dataArray);
        if($savefile)
        {
            echo('success');
        }
        else
        {
            echo('fail');
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You first need to load the library for security methods in your controller function:

```
$this->load->library('security');
```

If you still got the error message, make sure the security class file `Security.php` is in the

```
/system/core/ folder
```

and a line like

```
$SEC =& load_class('Security', 'core');
```

is found in the `/system/core/CodeIgniter.php` file.

Comment: Pllease anybody give me exact answer for this

Comment: @shahanshah alam: Please check the changes in my answer.